# Pre-allocation and optimization loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, optimization

My R script have the form:

```
for (j in 1:N) {

                  #construct the DF2 data frame 
                  #operations on the DF2 data frame 
}
```

Where N can be large (like a 1 mln). The columns of DF2 are defined 
one after the other with the formula:

```
DF2$column_i <- function(x,f..) #or constant or ....
```

DF$column_i can are a constant, a function or a loop "while". I tried to pre allocate defining DF2 before with:

```
DF2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=..,ncol=..))
```

and computing after the columns `DF2$column_i`, but I have not had any benefits.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: it could be easier if you could provide exact formulas/code of what you are calculating. maybe you do not need loops at all...

Comment: In R the best way to optimize a loop is to avoid it. If you have to/want to use a loop i would rather use `foreach() %dopar%` especially for construction of df/matricies

Comment: my code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

My code is of the type:

```
par <- data.frame(CA=runif(n = 50, min = 70000, max = 100000),
              D=round(runif(n = 50, min = 70, max = 90),0),
              P=runif(n = 50, min = 900, max = 20000),
              A=round(runif(n = 50, min = 50, max = 70),0))

parpa <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = nrow(par), ncol = 3*V))

comp <- function(CA, D, P, A){
vect <- rep('numeric', 3*V)

b <- 1
k <- 1 
while (((b+1) <= (D+1))&(k < V)) { 
a <- b+1
b <- min((a+8-1), (D+1))
vect[c(1+4*k, 2+4*k, 3+4*k, 4+4*k)] <- c(mean(DF2$Z[a:b]), sum(DF2$X[a:b]),
                                        mean(DF2$Q[a:b]), sum(DF2$AE[a:b]))
k <- k+1
}
return(vect)                       
}

#loop
for (j in 1:nrow(par)) {

CA <- par$CA[j] 
D <- par$D[j] 
R <- 0.01*D 
P <- par$P[j] 
A <- par$A[j]
COST <- 500    
V <- 5
#DF2
DF2 <- data.frame(M=0:D)
OB <- function(x) {
c <- COST*D*DF2$M/R
return(c)
}
DF2$O <- O(D)
DF2$E <- (D*DF2$M+2)/D*(D+4)
DF2$Q <- (CA-DF2$M)*D
DF2$X <- (CA-DF2$O)*(DF2$E+P)
Func <- function(x) {return(round(x/30, 2))}
DF2$Z[(A+2):(D+1)] <- sapply(DF2$E[(A+2):(D+1)], Func)

parpa[j,] <- comp(CA, D, P, A)
}
```

Comment: please, add this to your main post by editing it. Also, what is `V` and function `O`?